# react native use create material top tab navigator with bottom tab bar navigator in different pages

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I made a bottom tab navigator in the `App.js` screen and I tried to create a material top tab navigation in another screen `settings.js`

In `settings.js` I tried to create a navigation with the same code but shorter. Click between tabs became really slow but swiping worked perfectly. I then read you should put all navigation in one file (`App.js`) so it won't slow down.

My question is how do I put a `MaterialTopTabNavigator` and `BottomTabNavigator` in one file and then just export the `MaterialTopTabNavigator` to another screen?

`settings.js`

```
const settingsTabs = creatematerialtopTabNavigator ({
          Home:{
            screen: Home,
            navigationOptions:{
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintcolor }) => (
                <Icon name="ios-home" size={24}  />
              )
            }
          },
          Inbox:{screen: Inbox,
            navigationOptions:{
              tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
                <Icon name="ios-mail" size={24} />
              )
            }
          },
```

`App.js`

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
        import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
       
        const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator ({
          Home:{
            screen: Home,
            navigationOptions:{
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintcolor }) => (
                <Icon name="ios-home" size={24}  />
              )
            }
          },
          Inbox:{screen: Inbox,
            navigationOptions:{
              tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
                <Icon name="ios-mail" size={24} />
              )
            }
          },
          Search:{screen: Search,
            navigationOptions:{
              tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
                <Icon name="ios-search" size={24} />
              )
            }
          },
          Favorites:{screen: Favorites,
            navigationOptions:{ 
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
              <Icon name="ios-heart" size={24} />
            )
          }
          },
          Settings:{screen: Settings,
            navigationOptions:{ 
              tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
                <Icon name="ios-settings" size={24} />
              )
            }
          }
        
        }
        });
        
        
        
        export default class App extends Component {
          render() {
        
            return <Tabs />
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your components in single file, lets say helper.js and just return that component in a export function. Then import your desire function and render it any file.

**Helper.js**

```
const settingsTabs = creatematerialtopTabNavigator ({
      Home:{
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions:{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintcolor }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-home" size={24}  />
          )
        }
      },
      Inbox:{screen: Inbox,
        navigationOptions:{
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-mail" size={24} />
          )
        }
      },
});

export function Tabs(){
  return (
      <settingsTabs />
  )
}
```

**App.js**

```
import { Tabs } from './Helper'

render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Tabs />
      </View>

    );
  }
```

Comment: can you check this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999290/how-to-navigate-from-creatematerialtoptabnavigatorto-other-screen-react-naviga @game_dev